# UserRoles Not Working In Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-roles

I am currently trying to get the `UserRoles` to work in ASP.NET. I am facing some issues. For some reason it doesn't seem to pick up the roles from the DB.

I am changing the table name to meet my requirement by using the following code in `IdentityModels.cs`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("MyRroles");
    }
```

At First it couldn't find the schema and after doing some research I followed **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.ASPX)** article and that particular error disappeared. However following the article it added the following tables in my DB

```
aspnet_Applications
aspnet_Roles
aspnet_SchemaVersions
aspnet_Users
aspnet_UsersInRoles
```

Which I don't need. I'm doing a basic `if` statement to check whether the roles are working of not. And it doesn't seem to pick up the roles.

```
if(Roles.RoleExists("RoleName"))
        {
            Button1.Visible = false;
    }
```

In my `web.config` file I have the following code

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyConn" enabled="true">
        <providers>
            <add
              name="MyConn"
              type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
              connectionStringName="MyConn"
              applicationName="MyApp"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please. Thank you for all your help and support

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of the article and click on the link "Implementing a Role Provider" which takes you here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.ASPX which is what you need as you are using a custom DB schema rather than the default.

Comment: @KevinMain Thanks for the suggestion I've followed the article and now it's giving me this error `The 'System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'`

Comment: Have you updated the provider in your config to use your new custom provider?

Comment: @KevinMain Yes, I did and it says `Could not load type System.Web.Security.MyCustomRoleProvider` :/

Comment: Is "System.Web.Security" the correct namespace?

Comment: @KevinMain I just realised what you mean.. I changed the namespace but still the same problem :/

Comment: You might be better opening a new question specifically around implementing a custom role provider or at least editing this one with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do `a basic if statement to check whether the roles are working of not` then you need to store the roles somewhere, right? And since you want to use the default role provider you need these SQL tables. The default provider at `System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider` uses them. Because `Roles.RoleExists("RoleName")` will search these tables to see if the current user is assigned to the `RoleName` role.

If you want alter the way a user is assigned to a role, then you need to implement your own role provider.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        // your logic here
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        // your logic here
    }

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        // your logic here
    }

    public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
    {
        // your logic here
    }

    // etc...
 }
```

Check this article for all the available methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx.

Then, in order to setup your application to use your provider simply update your web.config file:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" cookieTimeout="3" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="MyNamespace.MyRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="MyAppName" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Of course, you need to update the code with your own namespace, options, etc...

After that, your code at `Roles.RoleExists("RoleName")` will execute the `RoleExists` method from your custom role provider.

Comment: I understand `System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider` uses these tables which I've had in my DB from the start. However when I run `Aspnet_regsql.exe` it generates the exact same tables but in lower case :/ And if I don't run `Aspnet_regsql.exe` I get an error `couldn't find the schema `

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you need those tables after all?

Comment: Sorry if I've confused you. I only use `AspNetUsers` from those tables and for UserRoles I've got a custom table which I need to use

Comment: Then you need to keep the default Membership Provider but use a custom Role Provider as described in my answer. Tables with `Users` are used by the Membership Provider. Where do you store your users?

Comment: At the moment I store them in `AspNetUsers` however that will be changing

Comment: Membership Provider and Role Provider are separate things. `Aspnet_regsql.exe` comes with data tables for both default SQL providers. At this point you can safely remove/ignore tables used by the Role Provider and create your own provider. After that, if you want to store users also in your custom database structure you will need to create a Membership Provider also.

Comment: Right, that makes more sense now. So I don't have to run `Aspnet_regsql.exe ` if I'm using a custom Role Provider?

Comment: You need to run `Aspnet_regsql.exe` only if you want to use the builtin [SqlRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) or the builtin [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx). I never used them in my apps. I always write my custom providers.

Comment: That has cleared it up for me. Many thanks for all the info :)